# Using a lightbox gallery

Tags: java, image, gallery, lightbox

it's been a long time ago i last scripted a website i'm just started making a portfolio website to show my photo's, i have al my photo as thumb image on a page and use this script for a lightbox:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp
it's nice and simple, but it won't work wel with my website layout my mainnav hover over the image and try to prevent this by this script:

```
// Open the Modal
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
  var mainnav = document.getElementsByClassName("hoc clear");
  mainnav[slideIndex-1].style.display = "none";
}
// Close the Modal
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
  var mainnav = document.getElementsByClassName("hoc clear");
  mainnav[i].style.display = null;
}
```

now my navigation bar will stay above the image but when you close the image it wont delete the style i gave him? 
can some one help me out?

Website http://www.kiekda.eu/p/gallery

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website where you have implemented this code? Just a guess here, but have you tried playing with the z-index for the `.modal` class in the CSS?

Comment: @Matthew I change the Z-index of .modal to 9999 and it worked -_- thanks!! its been 2 days of frustration just because i didn't see 1 thing i should had known. next Challenge is making the website multi language.

Comment: Great news! If it helped, would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing the z-index of the `.modal` CSS class to a higher number - change it from `z-index: 1;` to `z-index: 9999;`:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}
```